# Visualizing Pipe Names

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having Sysmon logs being forwarded to my ELK stack. In Kibana I am making visualizations of top specific events to filter out noise. So I am creating visualizations of specific events and adding them to the dashboard. It will be top 10 Pipe Names

In visualize I am trying to include pipe names. I'm doing a data table visualization. Under metrics the aggregation is count. And under buckets the aggregation is terms. Where I run into issues is the field. I'm trying to do event_data.PipeName.keyword, but this does not show up. How would I do pipes?

Comment: Perhaps what you ask would make sense to somebody who knows more about ElasticSearch and Kibana than I do, but it makes no sense to me. You might add a description or perhaps a small excerpt of the data table that you are trying to visualize.

Comment: I added a little more context